# My spring-mvc application throws 'BeanCreationException: Error creating bean...'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'..' on glassfish 4.1 server

Tags: spring-mvc, glassfish-4

I am pretty new to spring and I am developing a Spring MVC|Hibernate|C3P0 based web app using NetBeans IDE.NetBeans came with glassfish 4.1.1 server and my app gets deployed successfully and works fine in the default server.
Then I learned that this version of glassfish is buggy and gives trouble while setting up JNDI connection pools. So I installed glassfish 4.1 server and added it to my IDE. Now when I try to deploy my app, it throws a 'BeanCreationException'.

I was thinking the problem was due to some configuration error as I am using multiple configuration class.
So I already tried adding componentScan filter to exculude my WebConfig clas in my RootConfig class.

### WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.tgear.jdeproject")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    return resolver;
}

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry
         .addResourceHandler("/assets/**")
         .addResourceLocations("/resources/"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
```

### RootConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.tgear.jdeproject"},
    excludeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = 
EnableWebMvc.class)
    })
public class RootConfig {
}
```

### AppInitializer.java

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { RootConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/","" };
}
```

}

Below is the error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultIndenter
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!
Had to change the version of jackson core dependency to 2.5.2 and *TADA* "IT WORKED!"